# When do we use "Interaction‎s" (plural of Interaction‎)?

Tags: usage, singular-vs-plural

Is there any rule about when you should use "interaction‎" and when you should use "interaction‎s"?
And if there isn't, can you give me examples in which "interaction‎s" should be used?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see why you are wondering.

An interaction necessarily implies at least two persons, animals, events, etc.

> The interaction between the British and American governments on how best to defeat Nazi Germany was not free from friction, but may have experienced less friction than any other war-time coalition in history.

There were two parties, but a single pair during a single period for a single purpose. So it is viewed as a single interaction.

> The interactions between the English and Dutch governments during the seventeenth century, ranging from warring enemies to close allies, were so variable because the governments were pushed apart by trade and colonial rivalries and pulled together by first Spanish and then French expansionism.

Here we use a plural because, despite the fact that we are discussing a single period and a single pair, we are contrasting opposite types of interaction.

In other words, whether singular or plural is used depends in large part on whether similarities or differences are the topic.

Comment: I think the second one is plural because the author sees there were various occasions when an interaction took place. And the author of the first one views that relationship as a single thing over time.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Those are examples, not quotations.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow  Do you mean that you wrote the example sentences?

Comment: @Jeff Morrow Not in the least. You described the sentences as "examples".  But that term can be used for text written by oneself, or for text written by others but used to show a point of usage. I was not clear which you meant. Since you then said that you wrote the texts, I take you at your word. Plagiarism is claiming the work of others as your own. But you hadn't (as I understand it) claimed these texts as your own. And now that you do, I accept your word on the matter. All I intended to say was that you hadn't made their origin clear,  at least it wasn't then clear to me.

Comment: I deleted the comment that gave offense and apologize